# Can't add Seed data to database tables?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

When I want to add seed data to the database, I get this error and I couldn't solve it. Tables have many-to-many relationships.
I have attached my tables and context file below. Can you help me?

***The seed entity for entity type 'BasicCategory' cannot be added because another seed entity with the same key value for {'BasicCategoryId'} has already been added. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values***

```
    namespace BuyfiletData.Concrete.EfCore.Seeds
    {
        class ProductSeed:IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
        {
            public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
            {
                builder.HasData(
                    new Product {Id=1, StockCode="5484959", Label="Samsung S6", Status=1, Brand= "Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili)",  IsOptionedProduct=1, IsOptionOfAProduct=2400, MarketPrice=2600, BuyingPrice="2400", Price=2400, Tax=14, CurrencyAbbr="tl", RebateType=1, Rebate=200, MoneyOrder=300, StockAmount=5, StockType="cm", Warranty=200, Picture1Path= new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture2Path= new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture3Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture4Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture5Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture6Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Dm3 = 2554, Details = "Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili", Point = 15.8, Variety = "kırmızı", Size = "25", Color = "siyah", Gender = "erkek",},
                    new Product {Id=2, StockCode="5465465456", Label="Samsung S6", Status=1, Brand= "Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili)",  IsOptionedProduct=1, IsOptionOfAProduct=2400, MarketPrice=2600, BuyingPrice="2400", Price=2400, Tax=14, CurrencyAbbr="tl", RebateType=1, Rebate=200, MoneyOrder=300, StockAmount=5, StockType="cm", Warranty=200, Picture1Path= new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture2Path= new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture3Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture4Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture5Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture6Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Dm3 = 2554, Details = "Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili", Point = 15.8, Variety = "kırmızı", Size = "25", Color = "siyah", Gender = "erkek",},
                    new Product {Id=3, StockCode="5484959", Label="Samsung S6", Status=1, Brand= "Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili)", IsOptionedProduct=1, IsOptionOfAProduct=2400, MarketPrice=2600, BuyingPrice="2400", Price=2400, Tax=14, CurrencyAbbr="tl", RebateType=1, Rebate=200, MoneyOrder=300, StockAmount=5, StockType="cm", Warranty=200, Picture1Path= new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture2Path= new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture3Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture4Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture5Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Picture6Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"), Dm3 = 2554, Details = "Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili", Point = 15.8, Variety = "kırmızı", Size = "25", Color = "siyah", Gender = "erkek",},
         
                );
            }
        }
    }
-----
    class ProductCategorySeed:IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProductCategory>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductCategory> builder)
        {
            
            
            builder.HasData(
                new ProductCategory { BasicCategoryId = 1,MainCategoryId = 1,SubCategoryId = 1,ProductId = 1},
                new ProductCategory { BasicCategoryId = 1,MainCategoryId = 1,SubCategoryId = 2,ProductId = 2},
                new ProductCategory { BasicCategoryId = 1,MainCategoryId = 1,SubCategoryId = 3,ProductId = 3},
            
            );
        }
    }

----

        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MainCategory> builder)
    {
        builder.HasData(
            new MainCategory {MainCategoryId = 1,Name = "Cep Telefonu ve Aksesuar" },
            new MainCategory {MainCategoryId = 2,Name = "Bilgisayar, Tablet" },
            new MainCategory {MainCategoryId = 3,Name = "Erkek" },
            new MainCategory {MainCategoryId = 4,Name = "Kadın" }
           
        );
    }
                  
                   
                );
            }
        }
---
 

    class CategorySeed:IEntityTypeConfiguration<BasicCategory>
        {
            public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BasicCategory> builder)
            {
    
             builder.HasData(
                 new BasicCategory { BasicCategoryId = 1, Name = "ELEKTRONİK&BEYAZ EŞYA", },
                 new BasicCategory { BasicCategoryId = 1, Name = "MODA", }
                 );
            }
        }
```

---

This is the table where I establish the many-to-many relationship.

```
   public class ProductCategory
    {
        public int BasicCategoryId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int MainCategoryId { get; set; }
        public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
        public BasicCategory BasicCategory { get; set; }
        public MainCategory MainCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

---

This is my context file

```
using AlisverisagiEntity;
using AlisverisagiEntity.EntityModels;
using BuyfiletData.Concrete.EfCore.Seeds;
using BuyfiletEntity.bagla;
using BuyfiletEntity.EntityModels.Category;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BuyfiletData.Concrete.EfCore
{
    public class ShopContext:IdentityDbContext<UserEntity>
    {
        public ShopContext()
        {

        }
        public ShopContext(DbContextOptions<ShopContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<UserEntity> UserModels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BasicCategory> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MainCategory> MainCategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserEntity> UserEntities { get; set; }

     

      

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<MainCategory>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>().HasKey(c => new
            {c.BasicCategoryId, c.ProductId,c.MainCategoryId,c.SubCategoryId}); 
            
            
           modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductSeed());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CategorySeed());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new MainCategorySeed());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductCategorySeed());
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<Connect>().HasKey(c => new
            {
                c.ChildsId,
                c.GrandchildsId,
                c.UserEntityId,
            });

        }
    }
}
```

---

I am getting the error I mentioned in the title. How can I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have two classes to seed same entity "BasicCategory"
Try to Combine MainCategorySeed and CategorySeed and try again

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrong. Please take a look at the code I corrected. Could the problem be that I don't define foreign keys and primary keys?

Comment: you defined same BasicCategoryId = 1 in two records in same seed "CategorySeed" that's mean you try to define two basic ctegories with same id, change second record BasicCategoryId = 2 and try again

Comment: I did not understand . Where did I create two records?
(ProductCategory relationship table)

Comment: Here class CategorySeed:IEntityTypeConfiguration<BasicCategory>
        {
            public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BasicCategory> builder)
            {
    
             builder.HasData(
                 new BasicCategory { BasicCategoryId = 1, Name = "ELEKTRONİK&BEYAZ EŞYA", },
                 new BasicCategory { BasicCategoryId = 1, Name = "MODA", }
                 );
            }
        } change second seed record BasicCategoryId = 2

Comment: I did what it said, then I got this error, this time I got this error

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ProductCategory_SubCategories_SubCategoryId". The conflict occurred in database "BuyfiletDb", table "dbo.SubCategories", column 'SubCategoryId'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: add seed data to SubCategory entity    like :   class SubCategorySeed:IEntityTypeConfiguration<SubCategory>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductCategory> builder)
        {
            
            
            builder.HasData(
                new SubCategory { SubCategoryId = 1, //Other Properties},
                new SubCategory { SubCategoryId = 2, //Other Properties},
                new SubCategory { SubCategoryId = 3, //Other Properties},
            
            );
        }
    }

Comment: This time i got this error:D     INSERT statement conflicted with FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ProductCategory_Products_ProductId". Conflict occurred in database "BuyfiletDb", table "dbo.Products", column "Id".
The statement has been concluded.

Comment: typo mistake in prev comment update : class SubCategorySeed:IEntityTypeConfiguration<SubCategory> { public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SubCategory> builder) { builder.HasData( new SubCategory { SubCategoryId = 1, //Other Properties}, new SubCategory { SubCategoryId = 2, //Other Properties}, new SubCategory { SubCategoryId = 3, //Other Properties}, ); } }

Comment: I added Subcategory Seeds but gave the following error

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ProductCategory_Products_ProductId". The conflict occurred in database "BuyfiletDb", table "dbo.Products", column 'ProductId'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: share with me the  Subcategory Seed class please

Comment: Thank you very much, brother. Data has been added.